# Can't connect to WiFi, lspci isn't showing my WiFi card at all

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Good afternoon, I had a problem almost as soon as I downloaded Ubuntu. The first thing I tried to do was connect to Wi-fi, but I couldn't find an interface for that so I searched the internet for a solution. There I was suggested to install drivers for that, after knowing the manufacturer of my network card, but when I entered "sudo lspci | grep Network" I got absolutely nothing. Not a message that this command doesn't exist, not a message that I don't have a network card, it just throws me to a new terminal line and nothing else.
What could be the problem and how can I fix it?
All I get after using lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 06)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600] (rev 06)
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 06)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SATA Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 06)
00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 06)
00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b0 (rev 06)
00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b2 (rev 06)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b4 (rev 06)
00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b6 (rev 06)
00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b8 (rev 06)
00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ba (rev 06)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31d0 (rev 06)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor LPC Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 06)
```

And lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5830 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 18a5:0302 Verbatim, Ltd Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Are you sure it actually has WiFi? Try `lspci` only and find the line identifying the WiFi chipset. If it's an USB dongle then obviously use `lsusb` instead.

Comment: I have not found anything related to Wi-fi, but when the laptop was on Windows, I could connect to it, but after switching to Ubuntu this possibility disappeared and I can not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: We're expecting your [edit] to the question with the info gathered from the `lspci` command then.

Comment: Added, hope this helps in some way

Comment: A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: My version is 22.04.1

Comment: Can you attach the output of `lsusb` too?

Comment: Yes, of course. Already added.

Comment: There it is. Your WiFi card is attached via USB for some reason. "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter". If that's an actual USB WiFi dongle, can you share its model number with us? If not, I'll see if I can dig around and figure out which driver it should be using.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how i can find out his model number...

Comment: I dont think so. I cant get any internet connection by any way, so it means "git" Just dont gonna work

Comment: Getting the driver installed will require some sort of Internet connection for downloading it (well ok technically there is a way to do it without Internet on the WiFi-less machine but it is extraordinarily difficult). Most people get Internet during WiFi driver installation by plugging in an Ethernet cable or tethering with their smartphone.

Comment: But which drivers do I need exactly?

Comment: The linked answer contains a link to the driver, as well as all the instructions for installing it.